# Read json key and value as a variables to pass to another function in python

Tags: python

I have a json config file like this

```
{
    "sources":[
        {
            "name":"tbl1",
            "var":"L100",
            "query":"select c1,c2 from tbl1 where c1=L100"
        },
        {
            "name":"tbl2",
            "var":"M00",
            "query":"select c1,c2 from tbl1 where c1=M00"
        },
    ]
}
```

I would like to read name, var and query and send key and value to other python function for next processing.

Can anyone please how to write the script?
I have tried below code and could not to capture the values properly.

```
import json
with open('file.json', "r") as myfile:
    json_data = json.load(myfile)
    for e, v in json_data.items():
        for key, val in v:
            print(val)
```

Expected: Read the json data (name, var and query) value and pass to python function.

- read json
- capture values corresponds to first, second records, etc...
- pyfun(name, var, query). In this function I am going to use these values for further procedure.

Comment: Unfortunately `"but it did not worked"` is not a good description. Please update your question with the current output and the desired output.

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step. Add some prints, like `print(json_data)` or `print(json_data.items())` to find out where you go wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly get the `sources` key then iterate with each dictionary and get the required keys

```
for x in json_data['sources']:
    name, var, query = x['name'], x['var'], x['query']
    # do something
```

Comment: From Python 3.7 this can just be `name, var, query = x.values()` (Assuming the order in the file is consistent)

Comment: @Tomerikoo but sometimes json may not gurantee order of the keys

Comment: Sure, this is why I said assuming the order in the file is consistent. The json object is just a dict, and dicts preserve insertion order from Python 3.7